# how to make a single Main Menu active(has the colour ) in Accordian menu - jquery , javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/ucgff65k/13/

As you can see the `Menu 2`  does not have any child item , how to make the 'Menu 2 ' to have color when clicked (same color which appears while hovering submenu )

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#accordion > li > div").click(function () {
        $("#submenu li").slideUp();
            if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            }
    });
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
<li>
                            <div class="link">Menu 1</div>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li ><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                         <li>
                            <ul class="link">Menu 2</ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="link">Menu 3</div>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
```

CSS

```
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}



.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}





/*-------------Submenu-----------------------------*/


.submenu {
   padding:0px;
  display: none; 
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e; }

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #23222d;
  background-color:#CCC;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

#submenu li.active {
     display: block;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can assign menu 2 with a new class with the background or color (`.m2color`)
- add a toggleClass to menu2 with a click handler

Snippet edited to make slideUp work as well when re-clicking opened menu or menu2:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion > li > div").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
      $(".menu2").removeClass("m2color");
    }
  });
  $(".menu2").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("m2color");
    $("#accordion > li > div").next().slideUp();
  })
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/*-------------Submenu-----------------------------*/

.submenu {
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #23222d;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

#submenu li.active {
  display: block;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}

.m2color {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 1</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="link menu2">Menu 2</ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 3</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Original Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#accordion > li > div").click(function() {
    $("#submenu li").slideUp();
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
      //remove color when other menu option are clicked
      $(".menu2").removeClass("m2color");
    }
  });
  // you can remove the color by re-clicking on menu 2 as well
  $(".menu2").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("m2color");
  })
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/*-------------Submenu-----------------------------*/

.submenu {
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #23222d;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

#submenu li.active {
  display: block;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}


/* new class*/

.m2color {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 1</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="link menu2">Menu 2</ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 3</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how to remove this grey colour from menu 2 when any of menu 1 or menu 3 is clicked  . clicking should always attach the colour . 2nd click should not detach the colour

Comment: shaswatatripathy, edited. You can deactivate color by reclicking menu 2 or by clicking other option.

Comment: I suggest checking for children when clicking a menu item. If so, slide up/down - if not, toggle CSS class to update active state.

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/ucgff65k/17/ It should help you

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#accordion > li > div").click(function () {
        $("#submenu li").slideUp();
            if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            }
    });
    });
```

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
}



.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}





/*-------------Submenu-----------------------------*/


.submenu {
   padding:0px;
  display: none; 
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e; }

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #23222d;
  background-color:#CCC;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

#submenu li.active {
     display: block;
}

.has-dropdown .submenu a:hover,
.accordion > li:not(.has-dropdown) > .link:active {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
<li class='has-dropdown'>
    <div class="link">Menu 1</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li ><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
 <li>
   <a class="link" href="">Menu 2</a>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="link">Menu 3</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```